# How to draw a polyline in kivy garden mapview?

Tags: python, kivy, openstreetmap, kivy-language, polyline

I'm doing a project related to routes and lines of buses.
If I have a list of coordinates describing the route of the line, how can I connect Cordianta and Corradeta and draw a small line connecting them?
Each bus route has about 500 coordinates that describe the route of the line.

For those who did not understand, this is a kind of MOOVIT application

I will thank anyone who helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please specify the problem(s) e.g. `TypeError`, `AttributeError`, crash, etc. that you encountered. Provide minimal code and how we can reproduce the error so that we can help you.

Comment: Related question (with answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829408/how-to-trace-a-path-in-kivy-map

Comment: hello a have similaire probelem; did you find the answer !!!